# Saving associated many to many relation in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I looked at related posts but could not get my code working. I have device and project models which are connected thru `projects_devices` table. My models look like this:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects, :through => :projects_devices
  has_many :projects_devices 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects_devices, allow_destroy: true
end


class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :devices, :through => :projects_devices
  has_many :projects_devices
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects_devices
end


class ProjectsDevice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :device
  belongs_to :project
end
```

my device controller:

```
def new
  @device = Device.new
  project_device = @device.projects_devices.build
  @projects = Project.all
end

def create
  @device = Device.create(device_params)
end
```

and my device_param :

```
def device_params
  params.require(:device).permit(:name, :projects_devices_attributes => [:id , project_id: []])
end
```

My view:

```
<%= f.label :Projects_devices %><br>
<%= f.fields_for :projects_devices do |proj| %>
  <%= proj.select(:project_id, [], {},  {class: "form-control projects-devices", multiple: "multiple" } ) do %>
    <% if (@projects)  %>
      <% for @project in @projects  %>
        <%= content_tag(:option, @project.name, value: @project.id) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have a many to many association between two models. While creating and editing devices, I should be able to list all the projects available. And select only the ones required. When I save, the projects_devices table should be updated.

I have multiple problems here:

1. When I save a new device,

   a. the `projects_devices` table has only `device_id` but not `project_id`. `project_id` is null

   b. if there are 2 projects and I select only one, even then, two association records are created with only `device_id` (as mentioned above, `project_id` is missing). It should create only one association.
2. When a new device is edited,

   a. Project list, list of all projects is empty.

   b. I see 2 select boxes are displayed instead of one for projects(there are 2 projects currently).

   c. updating the device is not happening.

I checked the params:

```
"device"=>{"name"=>"ABC",
 "projects_devices_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"project_id"=>["",
 "298486374"]}}},
 "commit"=>"Create Device"}
```

My rails log shows that my application is inserting only device_id:

```
SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO `projects_devices` (`device_id`) VALUES (980190994)
```

Can somebody help me figure out the problem

Comment: I guess the `project_id` should be `project_ids` (just a guess)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, but try this params.
Maybe it helps. :)

```
def device_params
 params.require(:device).permit(:name, :projects_devices_attributes =>[:id, :device_id, :project_id, :_destroy])
end
```

Comment: No it didn't help :(